# Quickbooks Online Batch - php consolibyte SDK

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I am using the php consolibyte SDK to send Customer info and Invoices to Quickbooks Online.  This is going well, but I haven't managed to find a batch upload option in this SDK.  Is there one in there that I have missed?  If not, where should I go to find more info on doing so?